# opencv SIFT/SURF: how to determin whether the two images is matched or not?

Tags: match, surf, sift

I am new to SIFT/SURF of opencv, when I test it using two images, I am wondering how to determin whether these two images is matched or not.

For Example, I am matching image A and image B. 
When B is just a rotated image of A, It is easy to get the matches count , and then get the good matches count , and get the percentage by dividing them.
But I found out that it is not working for other cases: My image A is a 325*365 image; My image B is a camerashot of Image A from Iphone5 with 640*1136 resolution while A is not full in it; When I match them by Sift/SURF and imshow the matches, It is matching loud and clear in my eyes. But here I want to ask , How to determine whether these two images is matched or not automaticaly by my program.

Comment: And，When I am using SIFT, Image A got a keysize 751, Image B got a 2483, matches size is 751, and good match count is 17.
When I am using SURF, A got a keysize 887, B got a keysize 3778, matches size is 887, good match count is 31. If I use percentage , this gonna be really low.

Comment: Percentage as well as "good matches" as they defined in example is bad way to check "is it match or not". Correct way is estimation of homography or epipolar geometry using all matches with 2nd closest ratio criterion.

Answer (score 2):

If you can estimate homography transformation between images, images match. If not, no match. Here is example from OpenCV documentation.
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html

Function, which estimates homography, is
      Mat H = findHomography( obj, scene, CV_RANSAC );